# How to change background color of a header column and how to change text color of the header text inside the column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, aspxgridview

I want to have green background color in the header column and at the same time I also want to change the text color of the header text to white and make it bold.

So, this is what I have tried in my aspx

```
<div style="margin-left:455px;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" background:"#00a400" color: "white" font-bold="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_No" HeaderText="Branch No" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_Name" HeaderText="Branch Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_Address" HeaderText="Branch Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Phone_No" HeaderText="Branch Phone" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

This is my C# code:

```
private void DisplayBranch()
{
    string CS;
    CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DisplayBranch", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();
    GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

The issue is when I'm trying to run the aspx page, it is showing an error by mentioning that Gridview is not able to recognize background and font-bold.

It would be helpful if a recommended syntax solution is provided in my aspx code or in my C# code.

Answer (score 0):

`backgound`, `color` and `font-bold` are not properties of the server side component `GridView`.
Move these styles to a `CSS` class and set that class as the value for the `CSSClass` property of the `GridView`.
Alternatively you can try to hardcode these styles to the `style` attribute of the `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own styles for GridView header, row, footer, etc. More details can be found in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerstyle?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Here's an example for your reference

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" font-bold="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_No" HeaderText="Branch No" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_Name" HeaderText="Branch Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Branch_Address" HeaderText="Branch Address" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grocery_Phone_No" HeaderText="Branch Phone" />
        </Columns> 
        <headerstyle backcolor="green" forecolor="white" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```